# Playing video from the pause state in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

For custom videoview I had to override the MediaController (to change the design of the buttons and connect to the buttons pause / play a selector). The situation is this: put the video on pause and turning the application, and then again restored, the video starts playing again, and not from the point at which it was suspended, and therefore the question arose: how to make the video starts playing from the place , where it was stopped? What do I need to change in the VideoActivity?

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    VideoView videoView;

    VkMediaController mc;

    private static final String CURRENT = "duration";

    private static final String URL = "url";

    private Uri mURI;

    private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.video_view_player);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewplayer);
        mc = new VkMediaController(this);
        mURI = getIntent().getData();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mURI = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString(URL));
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT);

        }
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        videoView.setVideoURI(mURI);
        videoView.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        videoView.start();
        if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
            videoView.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(CURRENT, videoView.getCurrentPosition());
        outState.putString(URL, mURI.toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error/problem? what'wrong with this code?

Comment: no errors, but does not start playing from the current position, and from the beginning

Comment: did you check the value of mCurrentPosition?

Comment: did you check what canSeekForward returns?

Comment: did you check the value of getCurrentPosition in your onSaveInstanceState?

Comment: yes,but whatever I have done video restarting in VideoView after Home

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the problem is that `videoView.getCurrentPosition()` will always return 0 when you call inside `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`, cos at that time the video already reset, so call `videoView.getCurrentPosition()` when `onPause()`, this will return you the desired value.

Comment: protected void onPause(){
        videoView.pause();
        videoView.getCurrentPosition();
        super.onPause();
    } it's correct?

Comment: and I have to keep mCurrentPosition in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)?

Comment: in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) I only save the URL?

Comment: make the mCurrentPosition also static

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I thought I did everything right but it didnt work. Then I just changed the order so I first call `VideoView.seekTo()` and then `VideoView.start()` . That worked.
I also have `VideoView.requestFocus()` in there but I dont know if that matters.

```
videoPlayer.requestFocus();
videoPlayer.seekTo(position);
videoPlayer.start();
```

So if youre sure you position variable has the right value, this might be your answer.
You may not be able to seek when the Video is not loaded. Implement onPreparedListener like this:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener {
    VideoView videoPlayer;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
    position=savedInstanceState.getInt("pos")
    }
    // setting up the videoview
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
    Uri videouri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"));
    videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    videoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    videoPlayer.setVideoURI(videouri);

    }

    /**
     * Start the plaback when the video is loaded
     * 
     * @param mp
     * @see android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener#onPrepared(android.media.MediaPlayer)
     */
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //this is a TextView infront of the VideoView which tells the User the Video is loading- hide that
    findViewById(R.id.tv_video_load).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    videoPlayer.requestFocus();
    videoPlayer.seekTo(position)
    videoPlayer.start();
}
}
```

Comment: You call these methods in onCreate() or in onStart()?

Comment: oh youre right. I have implemented OnPreparedListener and this is all in the onPrepared method. Makes sense you cant seek if the video is not already loaded.

Comment: If its not working, try implenting OnPreparedListener and call this in the onPrepared() method. onStart() and onCreate() are in this context pretty much the same because youre Activity gets recreated when you change orientation. I'll edit my answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

[Portrait to LandScape LifeCycle Demo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ByH3gE9kODZ6DbU46E4X5hVVaoHXvVJ1)

```
    VideoView videoView;
    int lastPosition;
    int Video_STATE_POSITION  = 0;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            String message = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            lastPosition=savedInstanceState.getInt("STATE_POSITION");
            videoView.seekTo(lastPosition);
            videoView.start();
            Log.e("Keshav", "MainActivity onCreate() is called  savedInstanceState  lastPosition->" + lastPosition);
        }
}

  @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        outState.putString("message", "This is my message to be reloaded");
        outState.putInt("STATE_POSITION", Video_STATE_POSITION);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Video_STATE_POSITION = videoView.getCurrentPosition();

        Log.e("Keshav", "MainActivity onPause is called  ->" +Video_STATE_POSITION);
    }
```